# Are the coefficients of a Taylor series bounded when the function is?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Say that I have three real functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$ such that $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ for all real $x$. Additionally, $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ are logarithmically convex. Can I make any definite statements about the Taylor series coefficients of $g(x)$ in terms of the other two functions? In particular, I'm wondering if this is true:

$\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}|_{x=0} \le \frac{d^{n}g}{dx^{n}}|_{x=0} \le \frac{d^{n}h}{dx^{n}}|_{x=0}$

for all $n$ if certain conditions are met. I can see that this isn't true in general because you can construct oscillatory functions with constant offsets that violate it, but I'm not sure when $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ are convex.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f$ strictly positive, increasing log-convex function with $f'(0)=1$, put also $h=2f$.

Now $$g_n(x) = \frac 32f(x) +\frac 12 f(x)\sin (nx)$$

Easy to see that $g_n'(0)=\frac{3+n}{2}$, which can take any value we want.